# Get the size of hidden view - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have an empty `ContentPage` with `Grid` inside:

```
    <Grid
        x:Name="YellowGrid"
        BackgroundColor="Yellow">
        <Label 
            Text="It's a Yellow Grid"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            />
    </Grid>
```

In the overridden method I can get the actual size of a grid:

```
    protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
    {
        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
        // YellowGrid.Width equals to the width of the screen
    }
```

And that's okay. But if I will set grid property `IsVisible=false`, than the `Width` of the `YellowGrid` equals `-1`(that's logical as well). But is it possible to get the required size of a grid if it hidden?

**UPDATE**

I tried next:

```
    protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
    {
        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
        var size = YellowGrid.Measure(width, height, MeasureFlags.None);
    }
```

But `Measure` for `YellowGrid` returned required size for `Label` instead of whole size that grid will place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `Opacity=0` with `InputTransparent=true` instead of `IsVisible=false` to reach the same result of hidden grid:

```
<Grid
    x:Name="YellowGrid"
    Opacity="0"
    InputTransparent="True"
    BackgroundColor="Yellow">
    <Label 
        Text="It's a Yellow Grid"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Measure](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Measure/p/System.Double/System.Double/Xamarin.Forms.MeasureFlags/) method which determines size request for your control.